# Concentration of the number of edges inside a random induced subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, random, random-graphs, concentration-of-measure

Let $G=(V, E)$ be an arbitrary graph with $n := |V|$ vertices and let $r \leq n$ be a parameter. Let $U \subseteq V$ be a subset of size $r$, chosen uniformly at random from the set of all subsets of $V$ that have size $r$. Finally, let $X$ be the number of edges inside the induced subgraph $G[U]$ (this is the subgraph of $G$ including all the edges with both endpoints in $U$). How concentrated is random variable $X$ around its expectation?

One can use Chernoff-Hoeffding type bounds to first bound the maximum degree $\Delta$ of $G[U]$ and give an upper bound of $\Delta \times r$ on $X$. But this is a rather weak bound. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can use the method of bounded differences to get $\sqrt{r}\Delta$ concentration. see here: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/281b-sp06/bdddiff.pdf Not sure if this can be beaten

Comment: @SandeepSilwal It is not clear to me how to use the method of bounded differences. The degree of each vertex inside $G[U]$ is not really independent of that of others. Do you mind to explain more?

Comment: Reveal the vertices one at a time. Let $F_i$ be the conditional expectation of the number of edges in the subgraph after revealing the first $i$ random vertices. Then $F_i$ is a doob martingale and $|F_{i+1}-F_i| \le \Delta$. Now the method of bounded differences applies (also called Mcdiarmid's inequality) and you can show that $F_r$ concentrates in an interval of size $O(\sqrt{r}\Delta)$.

Comment: Very nice. It actually seems to me that $|F_{i+1}-F_i| \leq \Delta$ is in a sense loose, given that each vertex expects only $r/n \ll 1$ fraction of its neighbors to be inside $U$. But unfortunately McDiarmid's inequality seems to require a deterministic bound on the differences.

Comment: Maybe you can beat this by considering how the average degree compares to the max degree. It seems like if the average degree is much smaller than the max degree then you can beat the bound by excluding the few vertices that have large degree but of course all of this is heuristic and I am not sure how to exactly formalize this. I would be interested in any progress you make on this problem.

Comment: That's true. But my point was not really about average degree vs max degree. Even assuming that the graph is regular, I believe that the bound might be beaten. My point is that for most cases, the influence of a single vertex is not $\Delta$, but rather $\Delta r/n$.

Comment: Oh ok I see. Then some variation of talagrand's concentration inequality might be of use here. I will think about it.